# how do i test if function is called when button is clicked with JEST/ENZYME

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test whether a within a component is called when a button is clicked but I fail the test and receive 0 number of calls when clicked.

```
test('when clicked popUphandler function is called', () => {
    let popUpHandler = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(<StaticRouter><Header popUpHandler={popUpHandler}/></StaticRouter>)
    wrapper.find('.header__navClosed').simulate('click');

    expect(popUpHandler).toBeCalled(); 
})
```

```
function Header() {
    const [isPopUp, setPopUp] = useState(false);

    const popUpHandler = () => {
        setPopUp(!isPopUp);
    };

    return (
        <div className='header'>
            {isPopUp === false ? 
                <button className='header__navClosed' onClick={popUpHandler}>
                    </button> 
                : 
                <Nav data-testid='navigation' popUpHandler={popUpHandler}/>
            }
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: `Header` doesn't consume any props, so passing a `popUpHandler={jest.fn()}` prop to it in the test means nothing. You could target the button, simulate the click, wait for state to update and assert that `wrapper.find('.header__navClosed')` is now null or length 0, or that you can now find the "navigation" testid.

Comment: i created a test for that already by using toHaveLength(#), but i thought i should also test if the function popUpHandler is being called as well just to show even though i know switch between the button and navigation is working. But for future purposes, if i wanted to check if a function within a component was being called, how would i do so?

Comment: You should test your UI components by interacting with it's API anyway, i.e. props and the UI. If you want to test that button toggles something in the UI then test ***that***. IMO enzyme gets you too tangle up in messing with the internals of your components that it is hard to consider tests to be valid since how the rest of your app and users interact with it is entirely different. Components and users don't reach into other components and tweak internal state and implementation details.

Comment: oh okay i get what you are saying. Thank you

Comment: I know this is a little off-topic, but I highly recommend you check out [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) for UI component testing. I will warn though that coming from enzyme it will feel very odd, but once you understand better how to *think* about testing your UI it makes so much more sense and, just my opinion, allows you to write clearer and more effective tests.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is to forget calling `popUpHandler` callback prop. Just call that prop then it would work as expected:

```js
function Header(props) {
    const [isPopUp, setPopUp] = useState(false);

    const popUpHandler = () => {
        setPopUp(!isPopUp);
        // Invoke the callback from `props` argument
        props.popUpHandler();
    };

    return (
        <div className='header'>
            {isPopUp === false ? 
                <button className='header__navClosed' onClick={popUpHandler}>
                    </button> 
                : 
                <Nav data-testid='navigation' popUpHandler={popUpHandler}/>
            }
        </div>
    );
};
```

In case of keeping the component as uncontrolled way, you could switch your test to check DOM available as following:

```js
// Check your button was closed
expect(wrapper.find('.header__navClosed').length).toBe(0);
```

Comment: im a little confused, my component is working, and im not trying to pass anything into Header. I just want to simulate a click and check if the function popUpHandler got called. but its showing 0 for recieved calls.

Comment: The problem is you've written the component with uncontrolled style but you've tested as controlled type which makes your test not working. If you still go for uncontrolled you might have to either switching to check DOM available instead (checking that DOM available after having clicked) or make your component to be controlled

Comment: I dropped you another hint for testing your uncontrolled component

Comment: I've done a successful test on that already, thanks though. But i was told even though that is working. i should also write a test to show that popUpHandler function is also being called.

Comment: @Bpun1p If your test is "clicking" the button and the handler updates state, and you can assert the UI updated, then I say that is sufficient. That function and lines of code would show up on a code coverage report.